# How to include language folder in an executable c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a project and when I build it, it creates 2 language folders. These folders are created because I set the localizable property of my form to true so I have 2 files that Visual Studio added to my solution (like form1.en.resx). I configured 2 languages for my application. Is there a way to include these folders in my executable to only have an executable?

[image: My bin folder]

[image: Language files]

Thanks

Comment: Optionally, you could save yourself the headache of worrying about this, and simply have the executable create the folders when it launches.

Comment: How to create folders at launch?

Comment: That is where the satellite assemblies are stored.  The ResourceManager and ComponentResourceManager classes *require* those directories to be present without any alternative.  You'd have to spin your own localization scheme if you hate them, the kind of project that is often started but rarely completed.  Using the xcopy.exe /s option is much, *much* simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building a Winforms application (which I believe you are), when you build visual studio should already create locale specific folders in the output folder.
These folders will contain the compiled resources you've been adding per language and the .net runtime will load the proper one corresponding to environment settings automatically.
All that is if you let everything by default in terms of projects and items configuration.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can include folders in the executable, but you can embbed single files using the Resources and then acces them on runetime.